# Why HttpParams doesn't work in multiple line in angular 4.3

Tags: angular

From Angular 4.3 they introduced HttpClient instead of Http. 
in `HttpClient` I can't use `URLSearchParams` for url query parameter . instead of `URLSearchParams` I'm using `HttpParams`

This work

```
 var params = new HttpParams().append('a', '1').append('b', '2');
```

But why this doesn't work

```
var params = new HttpParams();
params.append('a', '1');
params.append('b', '2');
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The new HTTP client works with immutable request object and all its consistuent parts like `HttpParams` and `HttpHeaders`. To understand why see [Why is http request and all its constituent parts like HttpHeaders and HttpParams are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47930218/2545680) or read the article [Insider’s guide into interceptors and HttpClient mechanics in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/insiders-guide-into-interceptors-and-httpclient-mechanics-in-angular-103fbdb397bf).

That is why `append` method merges the parameters and **returns the new instance** of the merged `HttpParams` object on each call to `append`:

```
  /**
   * Construct a new body with an appended value for the given parameter name.
   */
  append(param: string, value: string): HttpParams { 
        return this.clone({param, value, op: 'a'}); 
  }

  private clone(update: Update): HttpParams {
    const clone = new HttpParams({encoder: this.encoder}); <-------
    clone.cloneFrom = this.cloneFrom || this;
    clone.updates = (this.updates || []).concat([update]);
    return clone;                                          <--------
  }
```

So here:

```
var params = new HttpParams().append('a', '1').append('b', '2');
```

the `append` with `b` parameter updates the object returned by the `append` with `a` parameter.

While with this approach

```
var params = new HttpParams();
params.append('a', '1');
params.append('b', '2');
```

the `append` always updates initial state of the `HttpParams` and all intermediary `append` operations effectively ignored.

So you have to use the previous returned value:

```
var params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('a', '1');
params = params.append('b', '2');
```

Or use the shortcut with `fromObject`:

```
let searchParams = new HttpParams({
    fromObject: {
        query: query,
        sort: sort,
        order: order
    }
});

const modified = req.clone({params: searchParams});
```

Or use `setParams` method on a request directly:

```
const modified = req.clone({setParams: {'query': query, 'sort': sort, 'order': order}});
```

Also, since 5.1.x you can pass object directly instead of an instance of HttpParams:

```
const params = {
  'a': '1',
  'b': '2'
};

this.http.get('...', { params })
```

Comment: Thanks. If i don't how can I modify my `params`. Suppose If I have `c` then how can I modify  `params` object If I have to rebuild my `params` I think its not good way .

Comment: sorry, can't understand. can you rephrase it?

Comment: @imran I think you can use params.set("key", 1).set("key", 2); this way the key will left with 2.

Comment: This seams to also be the case for params = params.set('a', '1'); as I have just discovered (angular 5);

Comment: @SoEzPz, yes,  in the new HttpClient module most entities are immutable

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com This is really odd, HttpParams is immutable, but HttpHeaders is not? Why is the API not consistent?

Comment: @Kugel, what makes you think HttpHeaders are not immutable? [They are](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b1f8eb14c8cd1f415b07d72e09d14bed77c8d4ac/packages/common/http/src/headers.ts#L123)

Comment: :/ fromobject and setParams, they are not documented are they?

Comment: @Ayyash, I don't know, I use sources as documentation :)  I believe they are only available starting from Angular 5

Answer (score 46):

For this to work

```
var params = new HttpParams();
params.append('a', '1');
params.append('b', '2');
```

This has to be changed to

```
var params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('a', '1');
params = params.append('b', '2');
```

It can be looped and added dynamically

Comment: This is the only solution which worked for me with Angular 5 . Thanks you very much

Comment: As it's said by Pratap A.K this is only working solution for me. I had to add the duplicate params such as {category:1,category:3}

Comment: This is so counter intuitive .. but it works .. thank you

Answer (score 13):

Since **5.0.0-beta.6 (2017-09-03)** new feature([***accept object map for HttpClient headers & params***](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/18490)) is available.

Now we can pass object directly instead of `HttpParams`:

```typescript
const params = {
  'a': '1',
  'b': '2'
};

this.http.get('...', { params })
```

or instead of `HttpHeaders`:

```typescript
http.get('/url', {
   headers: {'My-Header': 'header value'}
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually @Maximus made a pretty good explanation about the **immutability** of the `HttpParams` object, and all you need is to simply replace the `params` with its clone inside the loop.

Assuming that you *have zero-to-many* `params` available, stored in an array similar to the structure below:

```
"params": [
  {
    "key": "p1",
    "value": "v1"
  },
  {
    "key": "p2",
    "value": "v2"
  }
]
```

And according to the information above, the following helper function should help:

```
export const getHttpParams = (params: Array<any>): HttpParams => {
  let res = new HttpParams();

  for (const item of params)
    res = res.append(item.key, item.value);

  return res;
};
```

**Usage**

```
const backend = 'http://httpstat.us/200';
const params = getHttpParams(backend.params);

return this.http.get(`${backend}`, { params });
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the other ways on this post, but had little success. So I'm chaining params onto an `HttpParams` singleton and calling `toString()` to return a `string` type. I can then pass that to `http.get()` and everything seems to be working fine for building up the url parameters. Here is my `ng -v`:

```
$ ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
           |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.2
node: 8.5.0
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.3
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.10
@angular/common: 4.4.3
@angular/compiler: 4.4.3
@angular/core: 4.4.3
@angular/forms: 4.4.3
@angular/http: 4.4.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.10
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.3
@angular/router: 4.4.3
@angular/cli: 1.4.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.3
@angular/language-service: 4.4.3
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Here is an example that is working well for me:

```
// Simplified for example (I'm using Redux and won't go into all that)
private downloadState = { requestType: 'Auction', fileType: 'CSV' };

getStuffFromApi(): Observable<any> {
    const { requestType, fileType } = this.downloadState;
    const apiRoot = 'http://www.example.com';

    const params: string = new HttpParams()
        .set('RequestType', requestType)
        .set('FileType', fileType)
        .set('AuctionType', auctionType)
        .set('BackorderDay', backorderDay)
        .toString();

    return this.http.get(apiRoot, { params })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => Observable.of(err.json()));

}
```