# Angular >= 4.3, httpClient.get params empty

Tags: angular, angular-http

I'm trying to migrate my `Http` requests to `HttpClient` requests.
I was able to migrate my `post` queries but I'm facing a problem while migrating `get` queries. When I do so, my backend doesn't receive any parameters respectively, it tells me that the parameters are not provided and empty.

Did I do something wrong?

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

findItems() {
   let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
   params.set('something', 'hello');

   this.httpClient.get<any[]>('http://localhost:3000/apath/', {params})
    .subscribe((results: any[]) => {
      console.log(results);
    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
       console.error(errorResponse);
    });
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: see this [Why HttpParams doesn't work in multiple line in angular 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459532/why-httpparams-doesnt-work-in-multiple-line-in-angular-4-3/45459672#45459672)

Comment: thx @Maximus for pointing that out. Solve the issue with `set`. Hope in the future append will be improved to make my code a little bit more clean when I've to use many params ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Currently `HttpParams` is immutable, you should set params as below:

```
// for set method
let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams().set('something', 'hello');
// for append method
let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams().append('something', 'hello');
```

---

**HttpParams**'s `set` and `append` method will overwrite the original `params` instance with the newly updated one by `set` and `append`, and finally return the new instance.

So we can do it  in multiple lines as below:

```
let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
params = params.set('something', 'hello');          
params = params.append('something2', 'hello2');
```

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/SdHyVsZspzzLEm1ua0aO?p=preview)**

---

**Important:**

Since Angular v5.0.0, you can use `fromObject` from `HttpParamOptions` to add multiple parameters at the same time.

```
const param = new HttpParams({fromObject: {aaa: '1', bbb: '222'}});
```

Also you can set `object` parameters to `HttpClient` methods directly

```
const obj = {aaa: '1', bbb: '222'};
this.http.get('test', { params: obj}).subscribe();
```

Refer [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-multiple-params?file=app/app.component.ts), for the second way, please check browser's network to confirm the parameters has been added successfully.

Comment: Thx, I just noticed that in the same time you were writing your answer ;) I tried with append too, it didn't work. Set looks like the way to go. Hope it won't stay immutable, when I have many parameters to add to HttpParams, the code doesn't become that readable.

Comment: @PeterParker I agree with your opinion too. will mark the second way as unwork.  thanks for the information.

Comment: @Pengyy, also see this [Why HttpParams doesn't work in multiple line in angular 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459532/why-httpparams-doesnt-work-in-multiple-line-in-angular-4-3/45459672#45459672)

Comment: @Maximus thanks! Just look into source of `common/http/params`, seems `set` and `append` are the same. This has ever confused me for some while. so we may do `params = params.append(something, 'a')`?

Comment: @Pengyy, not exactly the same. The operation type is different which is passed to the `clone` - `value, op: 'a'}`. But they both return a cloned cop

Answer (score 0):

`HttpParams` is immutable. `set()` creates and returns a new `HttpParams` instance, without mutating the instance on which `set()` is called. So the code should be

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('status', status);
```