# Angular Http POST - adding multiple headers

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am struggling to add multiple headers to an angular http POST request.  Adding a single header works fine, but anything beyond that results in bad requests.    for example

```js
Update(url): Observable<string> {

        let _headers = new Headers();
        _headers.append( 'accept','application/json;odata=verbose')
     
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: _headers
        })
        let body = '"{ hey ... this is some data }"'
        return this.http.post(url, body, options)
            .map(data => { return data.json() })
    }
```

the code above generates the request properly. see below (from Fiddler)

```js
POST http://foo.wingtip.com/pwa/_api/contextinfo/ HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.wingtip.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 31
accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
content-type: text/plain
Referer: http://localhost:4200/resPlans
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: Ribbon.Tabs.TeamBuilder.Home=1920974|-1|125

"{ hey ... this is some data }"
```

If i add another header using .append, the generated request is wrong.. and my previous headers are gone as well..for example...

```js
update(url): Observable<string> {

        let _headers = new Headers();
        _headers.append( 'accept','application/json;odata=verbose')
        _headers.append('Content-Length','31')  /////this breaks it
   
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: _headers
        })
        let body = '"{ hey ... this is some data }"'
        return this.http.post(url, body, options)
            .map(data => { return data.json()})
    }
```

the resulting request (in Fiddler) looks like so

```js
OPTIONS http://foo.wingtip.com/pwa/_api/contextinfo/ HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.wingtip.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/resPlans
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

note that neither of the two custom headers are present.

and yes... i did import the Http, Header, and RequestOptions from Angular's Http library.

Guidance much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular >= 4.3, httpClient.get params empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500264/angular-4-3-httpclient-get-params-empty)

Comment: Why would you want to set the content length header?

Comment: true that Content-length is not needed.   i added the extra header only to demonstrate that an additional header of any kind breaks the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some TOKEN

```
_header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + TOKEN_VALUE );
```

If not works please try below full code with `SOME_VALID_TOKEN`..

```
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'});
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +  SOME_VALID_TOKEN);
    this._currentHeader = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    http.post(path, data, this._currentHeader)
```

Comment: Your code does not include TOKEN you have to add this parameter. I change my answer..

Answer (score 0):

you can try using some thing like this

```
 this.options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: new Headers({
      'header1': 'value1',
      // And more
    })
  });
```

And use this options in the request

If you are using the new HttpClientModule do something like this

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('header1', "header1")
    .set('header2', "header2");
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was due to CORS.   Because of my additional headers and http method (POST), the Angular HttpClient "pre-flighted" my request - turning my POST request into a request with the OPTIONS request method.  I originally assumed  the request had somehow broken, when in fact it was behaving as it is supposed to.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/