# NodeJS get value from formData x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: node.js, angular

I use HttpClient in Angular to send formdata to Nodejs.

```
 resetPasswordRequest(email){
    this.httpOptions={
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    }

    const formData = new FormData();

     formData.append('email',email);

    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3001/forgotPassword",formData,this.httpOptions);

  }
```

Later in NodeJS,I have app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}).

I am able to get req.body but in a different format as below:

```
{ '-----------------------------24875245787704\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name':
   '"email"\r\n\r\abcd@gmail.com\r\n-----------------------------24875245787704--\r\n' }
```

I am not sure what has been missed. Could you please clarify and help get value of email? I get req.body.email as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MDN `FormData`:

> It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to `"multipart/form-data"`

which explains why you're getting data in that format.

You could use angular's `HttpParams` instead:

```
const formData = new HttpParams();
formData.set('email', email)

return this.http.post("http://localhost:3001/forgotPassword", formData.toString(), this.httpOptions);
```

`toString` gives you `urlencoded` format. From [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams):

> Serialize the body to an encoded string, where key-value pairs (separated by =) are separated by &s

Comment: just to confirm. how do you get value of it in NodeJS? I get req.params as {} , req.body as {} , req.query as {}

Comment: `req.body` should contain the data what do you get if you `console.log(formData.toString())` frontend

Comment: thanks for asking to check console log. later https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500264/angular-4-3-httpclient-get-params-empty helped. And am able to get data properly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse formData in nodejs. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654747/parsing-post-form-data-node-js-express) or find similar. also are you sure you need to use formData? you can just send object in body