# Angular: append query parameters to URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, query-string, angular2-router

Im using this:

```js
    import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params.append('newOrdNum','123');
```

But this is not working, i dont append param in url. Any suggestion?

Comment: You want param like https://example.com/newordnum/123?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why HttpParams doesn't work in multiple line in angular 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459532/why-httpparams-doesnt-work-in-multiple-line-in-angular-4-3)

Comment: i want to append on existing params. I have something like this : example.com?param1=111 and now i want to append to get example.com?param1=111&newOrdNum=123

Comment: @Jota.Toledo its not add param in url with your example

Comment: Are you trying to send a request with query parameters or to change the current state of the browser URL? If its the second, then you need to explain better what you are trying to archive

Comment: i just want to append param to url...i'm gona handle that param on some other step..but right now just to append on existing url where i have other params

Comment: when your query params are changed, does that reflect in the url as well?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This could be achieved by using the `Router` class:

Using a component:

```ts
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({})
export class FooComponent {
   constructor(
     private _route: ActivatedRoute,
     private _router: Router
   ){}

   navigateToFoo(){
     // changes the route without moving from the current view or
     // triggering a navigation event,
     this._router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this._route,
      queryParams: {
        newOrdNum: '123'
      },
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
      // preserve the existing query params in the route
      skipLocationChange: true
      // do not trigger navigation
    });
   }
}
```

For more info check [this book](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html) and the angular [Router API](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)

Comment: should I be able to see it in the URL or this is behind the scene?

Comment: when `skipLocationChanges` is `true` then the url does not show it. which is fine. but i havent figured out what happens when it is `false`... Do you know?

Comment: when your query params are changed, does that reflect in the url as well?

Comment: What if this was a google map and the latitude and longitude were to be appended to the url such that any panning action on the map by the user would also cause the query params in the url to get updated as the lat/lon would change?

Comment: When `skipLocationChanges` is `false` URL shows the params

Comment: I have the same requirement but a slight difference. I need to add a token to all the route urls? Can we achieve this in a generic way than adding to every router.navigate()?

Comment: I agree that the "skipLocationChange" param should be set to "false" (or just omitted), so it answers the posted question.
When false, it adds the new location to the browser history.

Answer (score 42):

I had to adjust Jota.Toledos answer a bit so that it works for me, I had to take out the second and the last property of the extras - object:

```js
   navigateToFoo(){
     this._router.navigate([], {
      queryParams: {
        newOrdNum: '123'
      },
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
    });
   }
```

Comment: when your query params are changed, does that reflect in the url as well?

Answer (score 5):

You should write

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('newOrdNum','123');
```

Comment: And then (how to use the newly created params variable)? Otherwise this doesn't solve/do anything, and doesn't answer the question posted.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.router.navigate(['.'], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { 'a': 'b' }, queryParamsHandling: 'merge', skipLocationChange: true});
```

router: Router
route: ActivatedRoute

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Router` module. check this doc: https://angular.io/guide/router

You need import these modules:
`import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: how to only append on existing with router? without writing path

Comment: @None: are using `Router`

Comment: @None: read this doc please: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams

Answer (score 1):

#### Make sure while passing query params value should not be undefined.

```
      this.router.navigate([yourRoute,
         queryParams : 
              {
                key : (yourValue ? yourValue : '')
              },
         queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
            ]);
```