# How to create HttpParams using object for HTTP request on Angular 4.3 using HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, http-parameters

I have exactly angular version 4.3.2 and I cannot update because of dependencies. So for now I stick to this version. I have object with dynamic params (there can be other keys and values inside):

```
let query = {
    param1: 1,
    param2: 'a'
}
```

and I want to do something like:

```
params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append(query);
return this.httpClient.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/items', {
            params: params,
            headers: headers
        });
```

but there is not such params.append(query) method. So I need to iterate over the query keys and to add them one by one to the params. Is there easier solution for this?

Edit1:

according this answer this can be done since angular 5.0.0-beta.6 (2017-09-03), but is not solution for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46317900/1995258

Comment: Nope, seems like that's the way you do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428942/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK, thank you. I haven't found that answer. It's good reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it that way:

```
const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams().set('filters', JSON.stringify(filters));
```

Comment: Object.keys(params).forEach(function (key) { httpParams = httpParams.append(key, JSON.stringify(params[key])); });

Answer (score 17):

It can be done by using **fromObject** property

```
const params = {
    email:'abc@xyz.com',
    password:'qwerty'
}

const body = new HttpParams({fromObject: params})
```

Comment: The value of `fromObject` has type restrictions: either (1) all the keys and values must be strings or (2) it must be a `ReadonlyArray<string>`. cf. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParamsOptions#fromObject

Answer (score 0):

```
    let query = {
    param1: 1,
    param2: 'a'
}
    params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.appendAll(query);
    return this.httpClient.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/items', {
                params: params,
                headers: headers
            });
```

You can also achive this way

Answer (score 0):

it will be work

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('param1', '1' )
params = params.append('param2', 'a' )
```

Get URL be like

```
this.HttpClient.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/items', { params:params}).subscribe(
(response)=>{
   console.log(response)
})
```