# Add an Angular HttpParam for each value in an array

Tags: arrays, angular, http-parameters

I have a Http Request from angular that has multiple parameters. The one parameter type that the api takes is an Array of integers. So that section of the URl has the `similar format` to this :    `&Array=a&Array=b&Array=c`

Before i realized that i was just passing in the whole integer array as on of the parameters.

Here is what i thought would work but isn't :

```
    getLocationByBoundingBoxSearch(upperLeftLatitude: any, upperLeftLongitude: any, bottomRightLatitude: any, bottomRightLongitude: any,
                               maxResults: any, LocationType: any, requestUser: any, userClientIPAddress: any,
                               systemSourceCodeId: any, cesEntityServiceTypesToInclude: any, cesEntityServiceTypesToExclude?: any, 
                               entityTypes?: any, competitorTypes?: any){

     let httpParams = new HttpParams()
        .set("upperLeftLatitude", upperLeftLatitude)
        .set("upperLeftLongitude", upperLeftLongitude)
        .set("bottomRightLatitude", bottomRightLatitude)
        .set("bottomRightLongitude", bottomRightLongitude)
        .set("maxResults", maxResults)
        .set("LocationType", LocationType)
        .set("requestUser", requestUser)
        .set("userClientIPAddress", userClientIPAddress)
        .set("systemSourceCodeId", systemSourceCodeId);

    console.log("length of cesEntityServiceTypesToInclude : " + cesEntityServiceTypesToInclude.length);
    if(cesEntityServiceTypesToInclude.length > 1)
    {

        cesEntityServiceTypesToInclude.forEach(cesToInclude => {
            httpParams.append("cesEntityServiceTypesToInclude", cesToInclude);
        });
        
        var cesParamUrl = (this.mappingServiceApiUrl + "/LocationByBoundingBoxSearch", {params: httpParams});
        console.log("cesToINCLUDE param url  : " + JSON.stringify(cesParamUrl));
    }
```

> Notice

that I am trying to dynamically go through the values of the arrayType `"cesEntityServiceTypesToInclude"` and try to set a new parameter for each.

However in the Console log the full request with the params - it doesn't show any of the  cesEntityServiceTypesToInclude parameters.

I know that set can override values and since the `same key name` needs to be used multiple times i used `append` and not `set`

Comment: I believe i found why this isn't working. Check out the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459532/why-httpparams-doesnt-work-in-multiple-line-in-angular-4-3

Answer (score 1):

If think what you are missing is to reassign:

```
httpParams = httpParams.append("cesEntityServiceTypesToInclude", cesToInclude);
```

Comment: what do you mean reassign.

          httpParams = httpParams.append("cesEntityServiceTypesToInclude", cesToInclude);

Is inside a loop so for each value in the array a new parameter for each should be created.

Comment: A new instance is returned and you have to assign it. Please read this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459532/why-httpparams-doesnt-work-in-multiple-line-in-angular-4-3

Comment: Yes after more research i found that out. So i wasn't able to do this the original direction i was going.  However I came up with a different solution to get what i needed done.

Answer (score 0):

```
const paramsObj = {
      "upperLeftLatitude": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.upperLeftLatitude,
      "upperLeftLongitude": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.upperLeftLongitude,
      "bottomRightLatitude": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.bottomRightLatitude,
      "bottomRightLongitude": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.bottomRightLongitude,
      "maxResults": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.maxResults,
      "LocationType": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.locationType,
      "requestUser": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.requestUser,
      "userClientIPAddress": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.userClientIPAddress,
      "systemSourceCodeId": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.systemSourceCodeId,
      "cesServiceTypeToInclude": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.cesServiceTypeToInclude,
      "cesServiceTypeToExclude": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.cesServiceTypeToExclude,
      "entityTypes": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.entityTypes,
      "competitorTypes": locationByBoundingBoxSearchRequest.competitorTypes
    }
     return this.http.get(this.mappingServiceApiUrl + "/LocationByBoundingBoxSearch", {params: paramsObj})
     .pipe(map((res => res)));
```

The solution i was able to come with was to make a generic object. Where i was actually able to pass in the array types as a parameter that used the &cesServiceTypeToInclude=a&cesServiceTypeToInclude=b  format that i was looking for.